# USB wifi and In-built wifi problem!

Tags: networking, 16.04

I have a USB Wifi adapter, connected to my laptop directly through USB. The USb Wifi Adapter's chipset is MT7601U. '**lsusb**' shows no problems. Correct drivers for it loaded. However, when I switch off the laptop's in-built card, the in-built one switches off, along with the USB wifi one. However, when I ran '**rfkill list**', the output was this:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Note: **phy1**is the USB adapter!
Which, by my way of understanding, isn't off! However, in the indicator applet, it shows that both devices are off! Tried '**service network-manager restart**' and setting the in-built card to unmanaged mode, all to no avail.
Output from '**lsusb**':
**Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter**

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Output from '**iwconfig**':

```
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp6s0    IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

wlx20f41b591fd9  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Hoang-gia_han"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: 68:89:C1:85:1E:44   
          Bit Rate=58.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:6   Missed beacon:0
```

lo        no wireless extensions.
Words in **bold** is the USB wifi adapter, wlp6s0 is the built-in one.

Comment: I suggest you blacklist the internal device and leave the switch on. If you are interested in trying, please identify the internal: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` I will then propose an answer.

Comment: here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/20036321/, @chili555

Comment: @chili555, please why not post as an answer ?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @chili555 I solved the problem: blacklisting the internal driver worked great.

First I identified the driver:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4222] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:1050]
Kernel driver in use: iwl3945
```

Then to blacklist, create this file<sup>1</sup>:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-iwl3945.conf
```

add the text in the file:

```
blacklist iwl3945
```

Save and exit, and reboot.

Now if I turn off the in-built card it doesn't affect the USB one.

<sup>1</sup><sub>You can also just add this line to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` but creating a new file allows you to avoid editing system files</sub>

Comment: @Zanna Editing `blacklist.conf` actually IS editing system files. It is better to create a special file for custom blacklists.

Comment: @Pilot6 um - I recommended creating a new file and NOT editing `blacklist.conf`, hence the explanation?

Comment: It is OK, I got now that you wrote the whole answer actually. Good job! I was not attentive enough.

Comment: No worries :) @Pilot6 I'll clean up my comments when I remember to check back